# Libgdx - Random Color Change with Delay

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I'm having this issue with my game that I'm working on for practice and one of the things that I'm struggling with is having this random color change between these four colors red, green, blue, yellow. My objective is to have this ball bounce around the screen while changing between the four colors but I would like to have a delay or pause in between the swapping of the colors like for at least 3 or 5 seconds. So far in the code the ball seems to change but without delay I've tried using a few delay methods like Timer.Schedule but eveytime I use this the ball bounces around the screen but its all black and no color I would really appreciate any help? I felt silly asking a question like this because I have a feeling it may be a small issue.

```
public class Play implements Screen {   
Game game;

private Rectangle field = new Rectangle();
private Ball ball = new Ball();
private Paddle paddle1 = new Paddle(), paddle2 = new Paddle();  
private ShapeRenderer ballRenderer, paddleRenderer;
private float fieldTop, fieldBottom, fieldRight, fieldLeft;
private Color ballColor = new Color();
private Random rnd = new Random();

public Play(Game game){
    this.game = game;
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
    update(dt);
    draw(dt);

}

private void update(float dt) {
    updateBall(dt);
    updatepaddle1(dt);
}

private void updatepaddle1(float dt) {
    boolean moveLeft = false, moveRight = false;
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        moveLeft = true;
        moveRight = false;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        moveRight = true;
        moveLeft = false;
    }

    if(moveRight){
        paddle1.setVelocity(350f, 0f);
    }else if(moveLeft){
        paddle1.setVelocity(-350f, 0f);
    }else{
        paddle1.setVelocity(0, 0);
    }

    paddle1.Intergrate(dt);

}


private void updateBall(float dt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ball.Intergrate(dt);
    ball.updateBounds();

    if(ball.left() < fieldLeft){
        ball.move(fieldLeft, ball.getY());
        ball.reflect(true, false);
    }

    if(ball.right() > fieldRight){
        ball.move(fieldRight - ball.getWidth(), ball.getVelocityX());
        ball.reflect(true, false);
    }

    if(ball.bottom() < fieldBottom){
        ball.move(ball.getX(), fieldBottom);
        ball.reflect(false, true);
    }

    if(ball.top() > fieldTop){
        ball.move(ball.getX(), fieldTop - ball.getHeight());
        ball.reflect(false, true);
    }
}


public void reset(){
    ball.move(field.x + (field.width - ball.getWidth()) / 2, field.y + (field.height - ball.getHeight()) / 2);
    Vector2 velocity = ball.getVelocity();
    velocity.set(330f, 0f);
    velocity.setAngle(360f-45f);
    ball.setVelocity(velocity);

    //set paddle
    paddle1.move(field.x + (field.width * .4f), 0);
    paddle2.move(field.x + (field.width * .4f), field.y + (field.height - paddle1.getHeight()));
}


private void draw(float dt) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    paddleRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    drawPaddles(dt);
    paddleRenderer.end();


    ballRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    ballColorSwap(ballColor);
    drawBall(dt);
    ballRenderer.end();

}


private void drawPaddles(float dt) {
    paddleRenderer.rect(paddle1.getX(), paddle1.getY(), paddle1.getWidth(), paddle1.getHeight());
    paddleRenderer.rect(paddle2.getX(), paddle2.getY(), paddle2.getWidth(), paddle2.getHeight());
}


int THRESHOLD = 4000;
long lastChanged = 0;
private void ballColorSwap(Color ballColor){
    int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    if(rnd == 1){
        ballColor.set(Color.RED);
        }
        if(rnd == 2){
            ballColor.set(Color.BLUE);
        }
        if(rnd == 3){
            ballColor.set(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if(rnd == 4){
            ballColor.set(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        lastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }


private void drawBall(float dt) {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastChanged > THRESHOLD)
        ballColorSwap(ballColor);

    ballRenderer.circle(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), 20);
    ballRenderer.setColor(ballColor);

}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {
field.set(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
fieldLeft = field.x;
fieldRight = field.x + field.width;
fieldBottom = field.y;
fieldTop = field.y + field.height;
paddleRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
ballRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
reset();    

}

@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just add one more variable to save a timestamp?

```
int THRESHOLD = 4000; // 4 seconds
long lastChanged = 0; // timestamp
public void ballColorSwap(){
    // maybe call it here?
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastChanged < THRESHOLD)
        return;
    int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    if(rnd == 1){
        ballColor.set(Color.RED);
    }
    if(rnd == 2){
        ballColor.set(Color.BLUE);
    }
    if(rnd == 3){
        ballColor.set(Color.GREEN);
    }
    if(rnd == 4){
        ballColor.set(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    // set the timestamp
    lastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
private void drawBall(float dt) {
    ballRenderer.circle(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), 20);
    ballRenderer.setColor(ballColor);
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code. It might need some modification but hope you get the idea.

Comment: So I tried this out and it gave the same result the color changed but still no delay, but I feel like you might be on to something. Looking back at your code and mine I realized the issue might actually be the random generator I made, I think adding a delay around there should do the trick question is how?

Comment: I'd like to help but without seeing the whole code, it's hard to say.

Comment: here I added more of the code from the class hopefully this might light more up, its still a work in progress but if you need more I will put it up @EntryLevelDev

Comment: please see my edit. i moved the if statement and changed its operation to less than <